# How could i find path to file by his name?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Sooo guys I have to find path to the file by his name 
I've found this func. `findExecutable` but it's not working

F.e:

```
fileName <- getLine            ("file.txt")
filePath <- findExecutable fileName 
   case filePath of 
        Nothing -> error "I can't find this file "
        Just path -> print path
```

Even when I input `"/home/.../file.txt"` It's not working 
How can I fix it
The type of func is `findExecutable :: String -> IO (Maybe FilePath)`

I give to this func "String" I'm check the result with const. case of but all time i'm getting error

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? Are you getting an error? If so, please post the full text of that error. Or is something else happening? If so, please describe what.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I'm just getting 
prog-exe: I can't find this file "

Comment: What you have here isn't even valid Haskell; is `("file.txt")` supposed to be a comment? Is this a fragment of a `do` block, and if so, what function uses it?

Comment: @chepner I do think it was supposed to be sort of a comment, an indication of what the user input is at that point. This way, the rest of the program makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This would happen if `file.txt` is not, in fact, executable.

The [documentation for `findExecutable`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.22/directory-1.3.3.0/System-Directory.html#v:findExecutable) specifically states (bold emphasis mine):

> On non-Windows platforms, the behavior is equivalent to `findFileWith` using the search directories from the PATH environment variable and **testing each file for executable permissions**.

Try giving it the executable permission:

```
chmod +x /home/.../file.txt
```

Then try `findExecutable` again. Should work.

---

If you're trying to find the file regardless of it being executable or not, take a look at [`findFile`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.22/directory-1.3.3.0/System-Directory.html#v:findFile) instead.

Keep in mind, however, that, while for executables there is a rough definition of "find" (meaning "find anywhere on `PATH`"), this concept is generally not defined for regular files. This means that if you want to "find" a file, you have to specify precisely *where* you'd like to find it. This is what `findFile`'s first parameter is for.

Comment: I don't think a `.txt` file is meant to be executable, so I disagree that giving it the execute bit is a good solution, even if it works.

Comment: If the OP was trying to use `findExecutable`, then surely they were hoping to, you know, find an executable?

Comment: I don't think they were. I think they just used `findExecutable` to find a file in general, not knowing there are better options. And have you ever heard of a .txt file that was supposed to be executed?